# solr sunspot not getting arguments in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I was following Ryan Bates screencast and building a basic search, but decided I needed something better than plain MySQL text search and was hoping the Sol Sunspot gem might work.

As per the screencast http://media.railscasts.com/videos/037_simple_search_form.mov, I have setup my search within my model.

My controller has a simple

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.search(params)
end
```

And my model has

```
def self.search(params)
   if params[:search]
      search do
           keywords params[:search]
           paginate :page=>params[:page], :per_page =>20
      end
   else
     select('id,title,desc').paginate(:page=>params[:page], :per_page =>20)
   end
end
```

When I load the page without a seach, I get the correct output.

When I provide a search term, I'm getting

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I've tried both 'search do', and 'Task.search do', as that seems to be the difference between the tutorials I've seen http://tech.favoritemedium.com/2010/01/full-text-search-in-rails-with-sunspot.html, and the way I'm doing it, being passed from the controller into a method.

Any suggestions on how to get this going??

Answer (score 1):

As workergnome mentions, the precise reason for the error is that you've already defined a `search` method, which you're trying to call, from within itself, without the expected params.

What you need to call is the `solr_search` method, which is the actual method that Sunspot defines (named thus precisely to allow you to provide your own custom `search` method).

Furthermore, the object returned by the `solr_search` method is a Search object with some meta information about the search itself. You likely want the instantiated ActiveRecord objects returned by the `results` method on that object.

Putting those together, here's what you want your `search` method to end up looking like:

```
def self.search(params)
  if params[:search]
    solr_search do
      keywords params[:search]
      paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
    end.results
  else
    select('id,title,desc').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the "wrong number of arguments" because you've defined self.search as a function on the model, and then you're trying to reference the Sunspot search method.

Have you tried skipping using the Rails adaptors, and going directly with the Sunspot syntax?

```
Sunspot.search(self) do
  keywords params[:search]
  paginate :page=>params[:page], :per_page =>20
end
```

Might resolve your issue.